# file reading a mirrored alphabet in php

Tags: php

I have a text file to read mirror alphabet from it so if the pair is ** the program exits and if the pair are pq or db it must output "mirrored pair" ,so i confused why it isn't working.

```
    <?php
        $han = fopen("read.txt", 'r');
        echo "Ready <br/>";
        while (!feof($han)){
            $br = fgets($han);
            list($x,$y) = explode(" ", $br);
            if($x == "*" && $y == "*") { exit(0);}
            else if(($x=="p" && $y=="q") || ($x=="p" && $y=="q") || ($x=="d" && $y=="b") || ($x=="b" && $y=="d")){
                echo "Mirrored pair <br />";
            }
            else{
                echo "ordianary pair <br />";
            }
        }
        fclose($han);
    ?>
```

Comment: What are the contents of the file?  Do you have error reporting enabled?  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Is the file readable?

Comment: And what does it do instead of work as expected?